# SQL query to pick all rows from one table and selective rows from table 2

Tags: sql

I have two tables. Table `Tasks` having active tasks for a user. Table `CompletedTasks` having tasks completed by a user. Both have start and end dates. With a single SQL query, I have to select all rows from `Tasks` and only those rows from table 2 that have start date within the past two weeks. I am using SQL Server Express with Visual Studio.

Comment: Title says columns, question says rows? If the latter, use a `UNION` query.

Comment: fix your table structure. that should be one table with a boolean column `completed`

Comment: @rex i get the following error All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn **[DATEDIFF(week,..)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)** and **[union](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union.php)** in sql

```
Select col1 as col1, col2 as col2.... from table1 union all
select col1 as col1, col2 as col2.... from table2 where 
DATEDIFF(week, startDate,GETDATE()) <= 2
```

Comment: i get the following error ---  All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists

Comment: the number of columns you selected from both tables should be equal

Comment: I got it , thanks. The number of columns were supposed to be same.